# using bind this to pass argument down the pipe

Tags: ramda.js

I often create a pipe of small functions. At some point in the pipe, let's say at the 3rd level, a function might need to be passed an argument that the previous functions didn't need.

I could simulate a multi return from the first function in the pipe with returning an object with the yet unneeded argument, but I'm not sure it is a good practice. So I use bind and this to pass the argument specifically where I need it:

```
function errorMessageBag( fields, model ) {
    const execution = R.pipe( normalizedFormFields,
                              mergedModelAndFormFields.bind( this, model ), // Here I pass an argument only needed by this function
                              fieldsWithValidation,
                              requiredFields,
                              stringLengthValidation,
                              emailValidation,
                              urlValidation )

    return execution( fields ) // Parameter respects signature of first function in the flow.
}
```

You see in this example I pass to mergedModelAndFormFields an argument, model.
Works fine, but is this a common practice or bad practice ? If bad, what's the proper way to handle this ?

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable to me.

Comment: If you don't need access to `this` in the call, then currying the function might be a cleaner alternative.  But if you do, this seems fine.

Comment: Thanks guys, just copy these as answer and I will chose it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything wrong with the approach.

You could always define an inner function and use that in the pipe:

```
function errorMessageBag(fields, model) {
    const execution = R.pipe(normalizedFormFields,
                          mergedModelAndFormFieldsWrapped,
                          fieldsWithValidation,
                          requiredFields,
                          stringLengthValidation,
                          emailValidation,
                          urlValidation);

    return execution(fields)

    function mergedModelAndFormFieldsWrapped(fields) { 
        // model is accessible here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [Scott](http://[1]%20https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243641/scott-sauyet) mentioned in his comment, I would just curry mergedModelAndFormFields, preferably before being used in the pipe.  If this is the only place you need to curry that function, you could do it in place, like so:

```
function errorMessageBag( fields, model ) {
    const execution = R.pipe( normalizedFormFields,
                              R.curry(mergedModelAndFormFields)(model),
                              fieldsWithValidation,
                              requiredFields,
                              stringLengthValidation,
                              emailValidation,
                              urlValidation )

    return execution( fields ) // Parameter respects signature of first function in the flow.
}
```